# Could PageImpl<T>.getTotalPages() be changed to use Integer Maths rather than Floating Point?

Tags: performance, software-design, greensoftware

```
    @Override
    public int getTotalPages() {
        return getSize() == 0 ? 1 : (int) Math.ceil((double) total / (double) getSize());
    }
```

Could PageImpl.getTotalPages() be changed to use Integer Maths rather than Floating Point? I saw the code and wrote a test using the current algorithm vs one using integer division and modulus operators and the integer one was twice as fast as the floating point one.

Now the answer may be that the current implementation is readable and getTotalPages is not particularly a time-critical bit of code. My answer is due to the sheer popularity of Spring Boot, a large number of server applications are based on using it, all running in energy-expensive server farms. Every little bit that we can shave off the CPU usage saves the planet a tiny bit.

Comment: *"getTotalPages is not particularly a time-critical bit of code"* Yeah, this is the most important part. It is hard to tell if this is an issue without the context. For example, if `getSize()` is 0 or a constant, a JIT can optimize this function aggressively so there is no division not double conversion. `Math.ceil` is not expensive on modern hardware and a conversion takes only few cycles. Honestly, unless this function is called millions of times per second, it certainly does not worth optimize it.

Comment: I my experience the true cost are generally computations that are not required, bad algorithms, inefficient software design causing the implementation to be unfriendly for the hardware (bad cache accesses, scalar sequential code running at a high frequency). Numerical operations tends not to be much an issue alone.

Comment: *"Every little bit that we can shave off the CPU usage saves the planet a tiny bit."* The time of developer spend on optimization is often limited and actually pretty small (too much, certainly due to the lack of interest and the focus on new features by people who take decisions). As a result, focusing on the optimization of parts resulting in very small gain can prevent huge possible optimizations on part requiring a significant work. This is very common in my experience. For example, maybe we can use SIMD operation here at a higher-level. It would be several times faster.

Comment: Oh and by the way, integer division is expensive, especially for large integers. Floating point divisions can be faster regarding the context (especially with simple precision which can be use here as long as `getSize()` and `total` are not too big -- like <1e6). The result is likely dependent of the exact target CPU used. Things are not so simple.

Comment: Put it shortly : *"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."* (Donald Knuth).

Comment: Thanks for the comments Jérôme Richard, very enlightening.